# Implement obstacle avoidance methods and local navigation (move_base)

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, costmap, obstacle-avoidance, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to implement obstacle avoidance methods in Turtlebot2 (Velocity obstacles, VFH+. APF,...).
And I do not know if I have to use pluginlib  and do as D. Lu did. That is, implement the interface named nav_core::BaseLocalPlanner and do planning in computeVelocityCommands method [1].

Or maybe, it requires to do something else such as modifying costmap_2d [2], add PoseStamped ?

So, does somebody may advise me on what should I do first, since I am a beginner using ROS ?

[1] https://github.com/DLu/simple_local_planner

[2] http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286987/implement-obstacle-avoidance-methods-and-local-navigation-(move_base)/) by [sustainable](https://answers.ros.org/users/34385/sustainable/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an existing configuration here: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sustainable](https://answers.ros.org/users/34385/sustainable/) on 2018-03-30**:
Thanks for answering,  yet I did not get the idea : does it exist some obstacle avoidance procedures ?
I think dynamic window is not robust against moving obstacles, am I wrong ?
If I can reformulate my ask : where [in the code] should I put the local trajectory to do obstacle avoidance ?

**Comment by [sustainable](https://answers.ros.org/users/34385/sustainable/) on 2018-04-03**:
Any other implementation apart from elastic band or dynamic window ?

**Comment by [sustainable](https://answers.ros.org/users/34385/sustainable/) on 2018-04-17**:
Hello Mr. Lu, I have found one of your latest work [dwb_local_planner](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/dwb_local_planner)
Do you think I can use it in order to make my own planner ? Precisely, I need to modify only the local trajectory, I do not want to build an other m

**Comment by [sustainable](https://answers.ros.org/users/34385/sustainable/) on 2018-04-17**:
Precisely, I need to modify only the local trajectory, I do not want to build an other motion controller.
Concretely, I just want to give a list of PoseStamped that I have computed from a Costmap layer and current position.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-04-19**:
As I advised in the other thread, it will be easiest if you get a working nav configuration first, and then start tinkering with adding additional methods. Dynamic window isn't ideal for moving obstacles, but it still does pretty well.